# (How) can I access microSD Management from a Mac?

Tags: macos, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

I recently purchased a New 3DS, and the microSD card is in a really weird place. This leaves me with the most convenient option, microSD Management. Nintendo's website says it can only be accessed using Windows, but I don't see why it wouldn't work on a Mac if it's just standard SMB.

Can I connect using a Mac, and if so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on Nintendo's instructions it sounds like it's setting up a Windows share for the PC to access. On your Mac, go to Finder, select Help -> Mac Help, and search for "Connect to a Windows computer from a Mac". I would suggest trying these options to see if they work. Another option is to go to Finder and select Go -> Connect to Server and see if that can see it.

Comment: @Adeese If I use "Connect to Server", it says, "You don't have permission to access this server."

Comment: I'm at work now, but I'll try to see if I can get this working at home when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to get this working, but got the same error you did about permissions. :(

The more I read about it, the more it sounds like it won't work without changes on Nintendo's side. I found [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/3DS/comments/46rhsa/n3ds_xl_microsd_management_error_on_windows_10/) on the 3DS subreddit that said they could get it working on Windows 7, but not on macOS or Windows 10. My only thought is that maybe the 3DS is using an older version of the SMB protocol that macOS and Windows 10 don't support, but Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 do support it.

Unfortunately your best option is to probably open the back of the case, manually removed the SD card and use it directly from your computer. I did this recently (bought a 32GB microSD to replace the 4GB that came with my system) and I didn't have any issues with it at all. The microSD is formatted as FAT32, which your Mac should have no problems reading or writing.